# How to use third party control in my Genexus project

Tags: web, custom-controls, genexus

I am developing a web application in the Genexus 16. 
In this I  have to use a third party chart control(e.g goJs or syncfunsion). Please let me know how to integrate this control in my project.

Thanks in advance.

~Santosh.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the control from GeneXus Marketplace.
2. Unzip files
3. Copy the directory under the UserControls directory in the GeneXus
   installation.
4. **Execute GeneXus with the /install parameter**. (windows key + r> cmd) For example:
   \GeneXus /install
5. Check that the toolbox has added the new option under the User
   Controls section.
6. Enjoy!

Source: [https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5920,HowTo%3A+Installing+User+Controls](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5920,HowTo%3A%20Installing%20User%20Controls)

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: 1. I did not find these controls(goJs or syncfunsion) in the Genexus marketplace. Is there any other place or made a request to Genexus development team to get these controls?